# Select random image from list using pygame

Tags: python, random, pygame

So, I want to select a random image from a list. I imported all the images and made a list with all of the names(of the imported images). I am using random.choice to get a name from that list but when I run it, everything goes black. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Eff7M573) is the my the full code:

I am posting to pastebin since I can't post the question on stack overflow because there will be too much code.

```
    list = [one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten]
    image = random.choice(list), (y,x))
    rect = image.get_rect()
    screen.blit(image, (y,x))
```

Comment: What is `image = random.choice(list), (y,x))` supposed to do? I mean what do you expect by `, (y,x))`? It has to be `image = random.choice(list)`

Comment: did you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages ?

Comment: BTW: next time when you will put code on pastebin don't forget to set `"highlighting: Python"` and it will use colors to make code more readable.

Comment: Please fix the title: it looks as if 'iamgine' should be 'image'; and, since your first line says 'I want to select a random image from a list', that would make a good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how random.choice works. You just put pass a list/tuple into it.

```
image = random.choice(list)
```

This should fix it.